# How do I do display content in Django based on URL and all recurisive urls

Tags: django, templates, url, wildcard

So I have this in a Django template.

```
{% if request.get_full_path = "/blog/" %}
   do something
{% endif %}
```

Which does exactly what I want when I go to `http://somesite.com/blog/`

What I want to do is also include all subdirectories.

So something like

```
{% if request.get_full_path = "/blog/*" %}
   do something
{% endif %}
```

Unfortunately as far as I can tell Django doesn't do wildcards in templates.  So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
{% if request.get_full_path|slice:'0:6' == '/blog/' %}
```

Comment: Yup, that works!  I would have thought there would be a more typical way of doing this.  The more I work with Django the more I am realizing that is often not the case.